# How I can type in English and persian (Farsi) combined in Abiword?

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, abiword

As you may know persian has a right to left writing. When I try to type in Abiword in English and persian Combined,English words have been  reversed. Hear is a sample: It types " utnubuL سیستم عامل xuniL  می توان" When I want to type " Lubuntu سیستم عامل Linux می توان".This problem remains even when I first complete the persian text and then try to add English words. My operating system is Lubuntu 14.04.

Comment: When you type in Farsi only, is it correct?   Which languages have you added to Keyboard Layout Handler and in which order are they?

Comment: Yes When I type in Farsi only it is correct. even in other note taking app "Tomboy Notes" I can type combined in two language correctly. I add Persian(Farsi) to Keyboard Layout Handler and it is first in order (before English US). also I have checked "Keep system layouts" in Keyboard Layout Handler dialog box.

Comment: I do not speak Farsi but I could toggle between the two using LibreOffice.  Perhaps there is some hidden peculiarity in Abiword that prohibits toggling between a language that reads right to left and a language that reads left to right.

Comment: Yes Rex that seems to be right.

Comment: If you don't mind having a larger application installed you could install LibreOffice Writer (and the rest of the LibreOffice programs if you want).  I could not find anything in Abiword.  Perhaps someone else has an idea.

Comment: I have found an old document that may solve the problem that you are having.    http://www.abisource.com/help/en-US/howto/howtobidi.html  I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an old article on the bi-directionality of AbiWord.  It explains how to create bi-directional documents using AbiWord.  I believe that it may assist you in solving your problem.

http://www.abisource.com/help/en-US/howto/howtobidi.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Rex.The article that you have proposed was useful and my problem have been solved by tracking its advices.

Answer (score 0):

go top menu and selected :

Format >> Directional  >>  >> RTL section

Format >> Directional >> RTL Paragraph